# Generating Python code from XML tree

Tags: python, xml

What is the best way in Python to read XML from a file, build a tree, do some rewriting in the tree and generate Python code? (I'm slightly confused as in Python there seem to be multiple options such as expat, ElementTree, XSLT, ...).

Comment: "Generate Python code"?  What?

Comment: (1) See Glenn - WTF are you trying to do? Yet another XML format that thinks it's a programming language? Please not! (2) XLST and expat are not Python specific (the first is a programming language geared towards XML transformation, expat is a XML parsing library that happens to have Python bindings). (3) I think it is generally agreed that lxml is the best Python library for XML.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). It is easy to use and does what you want in a few steps. If you want to stick to the stdlib, then you check out [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (Python 2.5+) . The type of XML processing you want depends on your [needs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) and for high performance XML parsing, read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/).

EDIT: My answer is for XML parsing with Python and does not answer your last question: "generate Python code", cause that makes no sense :)

Comment: Note that `lxml` provides an `ElementTree` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I use Beautiful Soup. Its relatively easy to use and powerful.
[Check it out here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)